# Abstract Algebra elementary mapping Question 1

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $F : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be the mapping defined by $F(n) = n + 1$ for all $n \in\mathbb{N}=\{0, 1, 2, 3, . . .\}$, and let $I : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be the identity mapping defined by $I(n) = n$ for all $n \in\mathbb{N}$.

(a) Show that there does not exist any mapping $G : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ which satisfies $F \circ G = I$.

(b) Construct one example (or several examples) of mapping $H : \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ which satisfies $H \circ F = I$.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

(a) Suppose there is such a $g$; then:

\begin{alignat}{1}
(fg)(0)=i(0)=0 &\Rightarrow f(g(0))=0 \\
&\Rightarrow g(0)+1=0 \\
&\Rightarrow g(0)\notin \Bbb N \\
\tag 1
\end{alignat}

against the assumption that $g$ is a map from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$: contradiction. Therefore, such a $g$ doesn't exist.

(b)

\begin{alignat}{1}
(hf)=i &\Rightarrow h(f(n))=n, \forall n\in \Bbb N \\
&\Rightarrow h(n+1)=n, \forall n\in \Bbb N \\
\tag 2
\end{alignat}

Therefore, any $h$ which sends $0$ to any natural and each nonzero natural to its predecessor, fits. Necessarily, none of such $h$ is injective, because there is a natural $\tilde n$ (characterizing $h$, actually) which is image of two distinct ones: $0$ and $\tilde n+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  First, this is a somewhat famous example/fact.

The problem you will encounter in part $1)$ is that you will need to subtract $1$ from everything, in order to undo adding $1$.  But $0-1=-1$, so you end up going outside the desired range.

On the other side you don't run into this problem (reason?).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $F\circ G = I$.  Consider more carefully how these functions work on the element $0$.

You have that $I(0)=0$

You would have that $(F\circ G)(0) = F(G(0))=0$... but this is impossible.  Why?

> Clearly, $F(n)>0$ for all $n$, in particular for any possible value that $G(0)$ could have taken.  It follows that no such $G$ could exist.

Suppose that $H\circ F = I$.

Then in particular for any $n$ we have $I(n) = n$ and so $(H\circ F)(n)=n$.  That is, $H(F(n))=n$ and $H(n+1)=n$ for every $n$.

> So, $H(1)=0, H(2)=1, H(3)=2,$ etc...  This information alone is almost enough to fully determine what $H$ is.  The only missing piece of information is how $H$ map's $0$.  We can make any arbitrary choice for $H$ we want and it will be sufficient.

$~$

> $H(n)= \begin{cases} 0&\text{if }n=0\\n-1&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ is one such choice for $H$.  In general you could have $H_k(n) = \begin{cases}k&\text{if }n=0\\n-1&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ for any natural $k$ also works.